What is the highest weight of the representation of special orthogonal group $SO(n)$ on the space of harmonic polynomials $\mathcal H_m(\mathbb R^n)$?
$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}$
Let
$$
\mathcal{H}_m(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{P\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc ,x_n]\left| \begin{align}
P\text{ is homogeneous of degree }m\text{ and}\\
\Delta P=\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}+\dotsb+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_n^2}\right)P=0 
\end{align}\right.\right\}
$$
It is known that $\mathcal{H}_m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an irreducible representation of the Lie group $\SO(n)$ when $n\ge 3$ and $m\ge 0$ (§2.1.2.3 of Mark R. Sepanski, Compact Lie Groups). The action is defined by
$$
g\cdot P(\vec{x}):= P(g^{-1}\vec{x}),\quad\text{ for }g\in \SO(n)\text{ and }P\in \mathcal{H}_m(\mathbb{R}^n),
$$ where $\vec{x}=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)^t$ is viewed as a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
What are the weights of this representation, and which one is the highest weight? 
In addition, what is the decomposition of $\mathcal{H}_m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as weight spaces?
To be explicit, I expand on $\SO(2n)$, and the similar question is raised for $\SO(2n+1)$. We fix a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$, namely
$$
\mathfrak{t}=\left\{\diag\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0&-\theta_1\\ \theta_1&0\end{pmatrix},\dotsc,\begin{pmatrix} 0&-\theta_n\\ \theta_n&0\end{pmatrix}\right)\mid \theta_i\in \mathbb{R}\right\}.
$$
Let $\epsilon_j\in i\mathfrak{t}^{\ast}$ be defined as $$
\epsilon_j\left(\diag\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0&-\theta_1\\ \theta_1&0\end{pmatrix},\dotsc,\begin{pmatrix} 0&-\theta_n\\ \theta_n&0\end{pmatrix}\right)\right)=I\theta_j.
$$ Then $\Pi=\left\{ \epsilon_j-\epsilon_{j+1}\mid 1\le j\le n-1\right\}\cup \left\{\epsilon_{n-1}+\epsilon_n\right\}$ is a simple root system. What are the weights of $\mathcal{H}_m(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$, which one is the highest, and what is the decomposition as weight spaces?

See Example 1 in Section IV.1, the problems in Section IV.9, the examples in Section V.1, and Problem 2 in Section V.9 of "Lie Groups: Beyond an Introduction" by Anthony W. Knapp.

Nice reference mentioned by @Peter Humpheries , thx.

In addition to @Vít Tuček's answer, here is a geometric way to explain the weights of $\mathcal H_m$ and their multiplicities.
We fix $G=SO(2n)$.
Let $\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n$ be the elements in $\mathcal t_{\mathbb C}^*$ as in Excercise 6.14 in Sepanski's book mentioned in the question.
Thus, the positive roots are $\varepsilon_i\pm\varepsilon_j$ for all $1\leq i<j\leq n$.
The highest weight of $\mathcal H_m$ is $m\varepsilon_1$.
The weight space of $G$ is $\mathcal P(G):=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb Z\varepsilon_i$.
In particular, any weight of $\mathcal H_{m}$ lies in $\mathcal P(G)$.
For $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\varepsilon_i \in \mathcal P(G)$ (i.e. $a_i\in\mathbb Z$ for all $i$), we write $\|\mu\|=\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|$, the one-norm of $\mu$.
We have that $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\varepsilon_i\mathcal P(G)$ is a weight of $\mathcal H_m$ if and only if $\frac{m-\|\mu\|}{2}\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$, that is,
$$
\mathcal H_m=\bigoplus_{\mu\in \mathcal P(G): \frac{m-\|\mu\|}{2}\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}} \mathcal H_m(\mu). 
$$
Moreover, if $r:=\frac{m-\|\mu\|}{2}\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$, then the multiplicity of $\mu$ in $\mathcal H_m$ is given by
$$
\dim \mathcal H_m(\mu)= \binom{r+n-2}{n-2}.
$$
In words, the multiplicity of a weight in $\mathcal H_m$ only depends on its one-norm.
For more multiplicities formulas for classical compact Lie groups and highest weight of the form $k\omega_1+\omega_p$ (here $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n$ denotes the fundamental weights), you can see the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07839.

This can be found in many places usually under the name spherical harmonics. See e.g. section 5.6.4 of Symmetry, Representations, and Invariants by Goodman and Wallach. The highest weight of this representation is $m\omega_1$.
You can easily explore the weights in SageMath using the following code
W = WeylCharacterRing("D6")
v = W(5*W.fundamental_weights()[1])
v.weight_multiplicities()

but I don't know if anything reasonable can be said about them. E.g. in this example most of the weights have multiplicty 1 but then there are some with multiplicty 5 and 15.

You should be able to work out the multiplicity of each weight using a Gelfand-Tsetlin basis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation#Gelfand%E2%80%93Tsetlin_basis

@PeterHumphries Sure, that's one method to do it. As specific examples suggests, the number of weight multiplicities appearing is small which gives hope that there is a possibility of writing down a "reasonable" basis.

Yes, you can determine the multiplicity in terms of binomial coefficients. For spherical harmonics for $\mathrm{U}(n)$, I do this in Lemma 6.5 of this paper of mine: https://doi.org/10.1017/S1474748024000227
